# Azure Shared Ubuntu VMs dns each other

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, virtual-machines, azure

I have two Azure Ubuntu VMs. Named: myweb01.cloudapp.net and mypg01.cloudapp.net.

When I'm on myweb01 i issue an nslookup mypg01.cloudapp.net which fails:

```
azureuser@myweb01:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 100.74.218.90
search myweb01.a1.internal.cloudapp.net
azureuser@myweb01:~$ nslookup mypg01.cloudapp.net
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

azureuser@myweb01:~$
```

When I change the resolve.conf and point to google 8.8.8.8 everything goes fine. What am i doing wrong?

How can I change resolve.conf so that it will always search first to googles name servers?
Without being overwritten every dhcp refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Are your 2 VMs on the same Virtual Network? You will have to specify your DNS server on the management portal.

More info here: http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/

Comment: I have two seperate VMs no Virtual Network. But the nameserver I get from Azure dhcp doesn't exist.

Comment: Then, you will have to modify your configuration file. On the same link I provided on my first post, at the end of this page you will see "Configuring DNS values in the Service Configuration file"

They will forward you to the right documentation to modify your VMs config file.

Azure Service Configuration Schema (.cscfg File) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee758710)
NetworkConfiguration Schema (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/jj156091) - sorry for the formatting, i'm kinda new here but will learn how to answer correctly soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

The nameserver IP (100.74.218.90) should be ok, how are you setting up your VM (portal, powershell etc.)?  It looks like it's a Linux VM without a VNET, is that correct?  What region are you deploying to?

I tried to look up your deployment but "myweb01.cloudapp.net" is currently unassigned (i.e. vm is deallocated).

Gareth
(PM - Azure DNS)